# How to declare gridview control var as an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, object, gridview

Im pretty new to the object oriented realm and Im a little puzzled how to declare a gridview control and set it to an instance of an object. Im having trouble with the null reference exception error and thats because it is not referenced correctly.

```
 protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
       var MyLabel = (Label) GridView1.FindControl("lblTest");

       cmd.Parameters.Add("@X", SqlDbType.Char).Value = MyLabel.Text;
}
```

lblTest is the name of the label control in the gridview. But I need to declare this globally and I am not too sure how. If someone could point me to the right direction and help me with the syntax it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do have gridview control on the aspx page with lblTest in it then you need to find control on a particular row. In GridView1_RowUpdating do:

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
var MyLabel = row.FindControl("lblTest");
```

Here you could do:

```
Label MyLabel = row.FindControl("lblTest");
```

Var is used for  implicit typed variable. You can find this link interesting for [var](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)

Comment: GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
Label MyLabel = (Label)row.FindControl("lblTest");

Solved the problem. Thanks for your help :]